# Question regarding proof of compact embedding of $W^{1,p}(U)$ into $L^q(U)$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

The following is from Partial Differential Equations, Evans, p. 286~287.

**Theorem.** Assume $U$ is a bounded open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\partial U$ is $C^1.$ Suppose $1\leq p < n.$ Then $W^{1,p}(U)$ is compactly embedded in $L^q(U)$ for each $1\leq q < p^*$, where $p^*$ denotes the Sobolev conjugate of $p$.

Here is a brief sketch of the proof.

(1) It is clear that $W^{1,p}\subset L^{p^*}(U)$ due to the Gagliardo-Nirenberg-Sobolev inequality. Since $U$ is bounded, the fact that $W^{1,p}(U)\subset L^q(U)$ for each $1\leq q < p^*$ is also clear. Therefore, it only remains to verify that the embedding is compact.

(2) Let $\{u_m\}$ denote a sequence that is bounded in $W^{1,p}(U)$. We must show that there is a subsequence $\{u_{m_j}\}$ that converges (to some limit) in the space $L^q(U)$. By extension we can assume WLOG that the $u_m$ are defined on all of $\mathbb{R}^n$, and supported compactly, with this support lying in some open set $V\supset U$. Moreover, the consequences of the extension theorem allow us to assume that
$$\sup_m \|u_m\|_{W^{1,p}(V)} \leq C \sup_m \|u_m\|_{W^{1,p}(U)} < \infty.$$

(3) Consider the smoothed functions $u^\varepsilon_m := \eta_\varepsilon \star u_m$ first, where $\eta$ denotes the standard mollifier. By considering only small $\varepsilon>0$, we may assume that the $u^\varepsilon_m$ are all supported only in $V$.

(4) We first claim that
$$u^\varepsilon_m \to u_m\text{ in }L^q(V)\text{ as }\varepsilon\to 0\text{ uniformly in $m$}.$$
To see this, assume first that $u_m$ is smooth. Then
$$\vdots$$
(After some calculations)
$$\int_V |u^\varepsilon_m (x) - u_m (x)| dx \leq \varepsilon \int_V |Du_m(z)| dz.$$
**By approximation this estimate holds for general $u_m\in W^{1,p}(V).$**

Alright, this is where I'm confused. We know that we can approximate any $u_m\in W^{1,p}(V)$ with functions that are smooth up to the boundary, say $\{u_m^r\}_r$ with $u_m^r\in C^\infty(\bar{V})$. This approximation is carried out in $W^{1,p}(V)$. But how exactly does this justify that the inequality above holds for general $u_m\in W^{1,p}(V)$? Is it because $u_m^r \to u_m$ and $Du_m^r \to Du_m$ in $L^p(V)$ and the fact that $L^p(V)\subset L^1(V)$ implies $u_m^r \to u_m$ and $Du_m^r \to Du_m$ in $L^1(V)$, so we can write
\begin{align}\|u_m^\varepsilon - u_m\|_{L^1} &\leq \|u_m^\varepsilon - u_m^r\|_{L^1} + \|u_m^r - u_m\|_{L^1}\\ &\leq \varepsilon \|Du_m^r\|_{L^1} + \|u_m^r - u_m\|_{L^1} \\ &\to \varepsilon \|Du_m\|_{L^1}? \end{align}
Or is there a more 'obvious' way to explain this?

I'd appreciate all help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite. $\newcommand{\eps}{\varepsilon}$ $u_m^\eps$ depends on $u_m$ by the definition $u_m^\eps := \eta_\eps \ast u_m$, so you can only apply the estimate with $(u_m^r)^\eps$, not with $u_m^\eps$. (That is, you need to replace all instances of $u_m$ by $u_m^r$.)

The statement follows by approximation (for fixed $\eps, m$) if
\begin{align*}
(u_m^r)^\eps \to u_m^\eps &\qquad \text{in $L^1$}, \\
(u_m^r) \to u_m &\qquad \text{in $L^1$} \quad \text{and} \\
(D u_m^r) \to D u_m &\qquad \text{in $L^1$}.
\end{align*}
Now you choose $(u_m^r)_r$ such that $u_m^r \to u_m$ in $W^{1, 1}$ which entails the last two convergence properties. The first one then follows by the second one (and a small computation).

Comment: Hi. I've understood your logic, thanks for the answer. However, I'm still having difficulty proving that the convergence is uniform in $m$. Don't difficulties arise because $r$ actually depends on $m$?

Comment: You first show that estimate for all $m$ and $\varepsilon$ by approximation. To that end, there is no need for uniformity in $m$. Next, you use this estimate to prove convergence for $\varepsilon \to 0$, uniformly in $m$.